# How can I truncate a part of NSAttributedString within a titleLabel property in UIButton?

Tags: ios, objective-c

As question title, I want to truncate a part of NSAttriutedString.

Here's my code.

```
UIButton *btnWelcome = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btnWelcome setContentMode:UIViewContentModeCenter];
[btnWelcome.titleLabel setNumberOfLines:1];

NSMutableParagraphStyle *titleTextParagrahStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
NSMutableParagraphStyle *specificNameParagrahStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
[titleTextParagrahStyle setAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
[specificNameParagrahStyle setAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
[specificNameParagrahStyle setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail];

NSDictionary *titleTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor], NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17.0f], NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:titleTextParagrahStyle};
NSDictionary *specificNameAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor blueColor], NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17.0f], NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:specificNameParagrahStyle};
NSMutableAttributedString *attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@("Welcome To '%@' World!, 'VeryVeryLongSpeicificName'] attributes:titleTextAttributes];
NSRange specificNameRange = [attrString.string rangeOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"'%@'", @"VeryVeryLongSpecificName"]];
specificNameRange.location++;
specificNameRange.length -= 2;

[attrString setAttributes:specificNameAttributes range:specificNameRange];

[btnWelcome setAttributedTitle:attrString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

The btnWelcome width is set to width of `UIViewController.view`
The Color Attribute of specificName is very well done.
But, `setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail` doesn't apply.
Just shows below.

Welcome To '`VeryVeryLongSpec`

The contents is just clipped.
The expectation result is below.

Welcome To 'VeryVeryLong...' World!

Comment: Does `NSLineBreakByTruncatingMiddle` solve your purpose?

Comment: @atulkhatri Unfortunately, it doesn't solved. It just same result.